# Help solving a proof

Tags: proof-writing, real-numbers

My professor put this up on the blackboard and I was wondering how to solve it.

> *Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then |$x$|< |$y$| if and only if $x^2 < y^2$.*

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. We know the function $f(t) = t^2 $ is increasing for positive $t$. Since $| x| $ is positive by definition. Then, we have

$$ |x| < |y| \implies |x|^2 < |y|^2 \implies x^2 < y^2 $$

Since $|x|^2 = x^2 $

Suppose now $x^2 < y^2$. taking square roots we have $|x| < |y| $.

Comment: Exactely. I would add for the direction $"\rightarrow"$ that the conclusion follows from the fact that $f(t) := t^2$ is increasing for positive $t$.

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\notag \\ #1 \;\;\; & \;\;\; \text{"#2"} \notag \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\notag \end{align}}
$As another answer says, the key is to use (strict) 'increasingness' of a function.  This is usually defined as
$$
\tag{0} f\text{ is increasing} \;\equiv\; \langle \forall x,y :: x < y \;\Rightarrow\; f(x) < f(y) \rangle
$$
However, an equivalent (why?) definition that I find easier to use in practice is
$$
\tag{1} f\text{ is increasing} \;\equiv\; \langle \forall x,y :: x < y \;\equiv\; f(x) < f(y) \rangle
$$
Now there are two ways to do this proof, depending on which side you start.  The simplest starting point seems to be $\;x^2 < y^2\;$: we know that $\;\cdot^2\;$ is increasing, but only for non-negative arguments! That leads to the following proof.

---

For every $\;x,y\;$, we have

$$\calc
x^2 < y^2
\calcop{\equiv}{rewrite -- to make the arguments of $\;\cdot^2\;$ non-negative}
|x|^2 < |y|^2
\calcop{\equiv}{by (1) and the fact that $\;\cdot^2\;$ is increasing for non-negative arguments}
|x| < |y|
\endcalc$$

---

Alternatively, we can start on the other side, and start massaging $\;|\cdot|\;$ into a form that includes $\;\cdot^2\;$:

---

For every $\;x,y\;$,

$$\calc
|x| < |y|
\calcop{\equiv}{rewrite}
\sqrt{x^2} < \sqrt{y^2}
\calcop{\equiv}{by (1) and the fact that $\;\sqrt{\cdot}\;$ is increasing for non-negative arguments}
x^2 < y^2
\endcalc$$

---

Finally, note that these are essentially the proofs from the earlier answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Just use the fact that $$|\,\,\!x\!\,|=\sqrt{x^2},$$ then square both sides and...